# How to extrude the Grease Pencil draw like in sketchup?

Tags: mesh, grease-pencil, extrude, 2d, conversion

I drew some curves with the Grease Pencil, and I want to transform it into a 3d wall.

I tried researching a lot of how to do it, but i was really not able to found nothing.

In the object mode, with the pencil selected, the option to Convert to Mesh doesn't appear for me.

I also tried adding a plane behind it, and extrude the hole draw in the edit mode, but it didn't work as expected.

What can I do?

Thanks

[image]